# Drupal 7: How to create multi record form?

Tags: forms, drupal, themes

I work on project in Drupal 7.
There I have a custom module which has couple of forms. One of the forms should enable the user to edit table from the database inline.

How can i create a form which will look like a grid and will enable me to edit each row inline?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try to see if Live Table works for you, not sure who it plays with DB.
http://www.9lessons.info/2011/03/live-table-edit-with-jquery-and-ajax.html